# List children on child post

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, query-posts, child-pages

I have a custom post type with children posts. If I'm viewing one of the children post how can I list other children posts that uses the same parent?

Comment: do you mean something like related posts

Comment: yes quite similar except this is by post parent

Comment: I'm a bit late :-), but the solution from @Roberthue should work. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the list of other posts with same post parent by running a custom query. You should supply parent post id in `post_parent` parameter to [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and exclude current post from custom query.

So this will be the custom query.

```
$parentpost = wp_get_post_parent_id( $post->ID );

if ( $parentpost && $parentpost != '0' ) {

    $currentpost = array( $post->ID );

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'cpt-name',
        'post_parent' => $parentpost,
        'post__not_in' => $currentpost,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'paged' => $paged,
    );

    $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
            the_title();
        endwhile;

    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();

} else {

    echo "Do something else.";

}
```

Oh and also, you will have to add your custom post type name in above code to work. I added `cpt-name` right now as an example. I hope this helps.

Comment: The code works except when I view the parent post it lists other parent posts which I don't want. How can I make if it's a parent post do something else?

Comment: You can always add a check, to do/show something else if user is on parent post. I have updated the answer, use updated code.